# Adding column of extracted character to file without using pandas

Tags: python

I have a csv file data that is as shown

```
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,A,MIN1 MX2 PT34
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,B,MIN1 G2 Y4 R6 MX2 FL3 PT9
09-oct-2010 00:00:43,A,TG1 MIN1 PT28
```

I am trying to extract the digit after "PT". After extracting the numbers, I would like to add the numbers to a new column such as

```
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,A,MIN1 MX2 PT34,34
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,B,MIN1 G2 Y4 R6 MX2 FL3 PT9,9
09-oct-2010 00:00:43,A,TG1 MIN1 PT28,28
```

Below is my code. Please advice on how to extract without using pandas and add back to the csv file. If using pandas, how can i read the numbers from PT

```
x = str1Var.get()
with open(x,"r") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    for line in infile.readlines():
        dur = line[-4:-2]
        print(dur)
```

The dur contain whole row of numbers extracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me the exact output of what you're expecting without using any specific package.

```
sourceUrl = open(r"C:\Users\seramu\Desktop\tools\stackoverflow\dummy.txt", "r")
csvOutput = open(r"C:\Users\seramu\Desktop\tools\stackoverflow\dummycsv.csv", "w")
for st in sourceUrl:
    csvOutput.write(st.strip('\n') + ',')
    newlist = st.split(" ")
    newstr = ''.join((ch if ch in '0123456789.-e' else ' ') for ch in newlist[-1])
    listnum = [int(i) for i in newstr.split()]
    csvOutput.write(str(listnum[0]) + '\n')


csvOutput.close()
sourceUrl.close()
```

Input file:

```
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,A,MIN1 MX2 PT34
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,B,MIN1 G2 Y4 R6 MX2 FL3 PT9
09-oct-2010 00:00:43,A,TG1 MIN1 PT28
```

Output file:

```
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,A,MIN1 MX2 PT34,34
09-oct-2010 00:00:00,B,MIN1 G2 Y4 R6 MX2 FL3 PT9,9
09-oct-2010 00:00:43,A,TG1 MIN1 PT28,28
```

"dur = line[-4:-2]" in the question will not fetch the proper number always. So I have split the string in to a list and considered only the last element of the list. Once I have the last element I am checking character wise since we are not sure how many digits will be present in that so iterating thru it to find the numbers present in that. While iterating I am checking whether it is a character or a number and storing it in a new list and writing it in the file with a newline character.

Comment: Hi! It worked! But do you mind explaining the steps you took for me? sorry for any inconvenience caused

Comment: I have edited and added the explanation in the answer itself :) let me know in case if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Would like to consult you if I want to search within the string to get the number after certain character(e.g. after 'Y' or after 'R'). how can I edit my code to suit such example?